# Disable automatic carriage return in emacs HTML mode

Tags: html, emacs, editing

I'm using emacs in HTML mode. When I type about 70 columns of text, it automatically performs a carriage return, breaking up the text over two lines. Is there a way to disable and/or modify this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have auto-fill mode turned on. Just do `M-x auto-fill-mode` to disable it. For a more permanent solution, add

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)
```

to your `.emacs` file.